# javascript onclick set to variable function name?

Tags: javascript, onclick, naming-conventions

Is it possible to use JavaScript to set the click event to a variable function name?

I want to dynamically set each of the selected elements to functions that the names are declared elsewhere. These functions are class methods. I don't know if this is why it's not working.

I know this is funky monkey stuff, but it's preferable to the alternative of using a switch, with all the functions I have to parse through.

function name get

```
// get last part of the string
var x = strName.split("_");
var y = x[x.length - 1];
```

This works

```
holder[j].onclick = function(){ini['add']();};
```

This does not, for some reason

```
holder[j].onclick = function(){ini[y]();}; // I checked: y == 'add' in the test
```

Comment: Where did you test that `y === 'add'`? Try checking within the `onclick` handler itself.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't got a closure so that *y* (and hence `ini[y]`) resolves to an unexpected value when the function is called? Oh, and define "doesn't work". Is there an error? Nothing happens? Coffee goes cold? …?

Comment: Consider making y a global variable.

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner; I didn't realize the time and had to go to bed.
RobG and sideroxylon(in a roundabout way) got my brain to click where it needed to, and I've determined the error in my judgement and a proper workaround for it. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found that this does *not* work. The onclick is *not* set to the function I want it to be, just the statement

```
ini[y]();
```

As y is no longer in scope after the setup is complete (and even if it was, there's no saying that it would be the correct y, as it has a different value each iteration), I've had to pull it out to make it determine function on the fly.

Using this:

```
holder[j].onclick = function(){clickMaster(this);};
```

Then this:

```
function clickMaster(ele){
    // pull out strName based on ele
    var x = strName.split("_");
    var y = x[x.length - 1];
    ini[y]();
}
```

Rather than just trying to set the onclick directly to the class method.